# returning an array from smart contract but getting empty array in my Dapps but returning an filled array on remix when i deploy smartcontract on remix

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

//This is my solidity contract

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract Funder{
    mapping(address=>bool) contributors; 
    mapping(address=>uint) contributes;
    
    uint public cont;
    address public manager;
    uint public extra; 
    
    struct Request{
        uint id;
        string img_hash;
        string file_hash;
        string category;
        string description;
        address payable recipient;
        uint deadline;
        uint target;
        uint raisedAmount;
        bool completed;
        uint noOfDonors;
        bool approved;
        
        
    }
    mapping(address=>uint[]) whocreaterequest;
    mapping(uint=>Request) public requests;
    uint public numRequests;
    constructor(){
        manager=msg.sender;
    }
    receive() external payable{}

    
        function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint) 
        {
            return address(this).balance;
        }

    function createRequests(string memory cate,string memory _description,string memory imghash,string memory filehash,address payable _recipient,uint _time,uint _target) public {
        Request storage newRequest=requests[numRequests];
        newRequest.id=numRequests;
        newRequest.category=cate;
        newRequest.img_hash=imghash;
        newRequest.file_hash=filehash;
        newRequest.description=_description;
        newRequest.recipient=_recipient;
        newRequest.deadline=block.timestamp+_time; 
        newRequest.target=_target;
        newRequest.raisedAmount=0;
        newRequest.completed=false;
        newRequest.approved=false;
        newRequest.noOfDonors=0; 
        whocreaterequest[msg.sender].push(numRequests);
        numRequests++;
        
    }

    function seemyrequests() public view returns(Request[] memory)
    {
        Request[] memory yrequest = new Request[]((whocreaterequest[msg.sender]).length);
        
         for (uint i = 0; i < whocreaterequest[msg.sender].length; i++) 
         {
             Request storage lBi = requests[(whocreaterequest[msg.sender])[i]];
             yrequest[i]=lBi;
         }
        return yrequest;
    }


    
  
    

}
```

#here I am fetching the data of seemyrequests in App.js of my dapp using getyourrequest function. This function calls the smart contract function seemyrequests but it is returning an empty array and is unable to set the state.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const getyourrequest= async ()=>{
     const {web3,contract} = web3Api;
    var p=await contract?.seemyrequests({
      from:account,
    }).then((p)=> {
      // console.log("p:-", p);
     setyour(p);  
    }
    );
 };
 web3Api.web3 && getyourrequest();
},[web3Api,reload]);
```

#But getting an empty array when I tried to call this function from app.js. This smart contract is working Fine on remix returning proper data. Unable to find out what's wrong with this.